# Why does rigify generate my rig so small?

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm a beginner with Blender, I'm trying to use it to create some basic 3d character models for my program. I'm trying to use the plugin rigify to generate a rig to create animations for my character. I add a `Human (Meta-rig) armature` then scale it/move it to match my mesh. However, when I hit "generate" to create the rig, I get the following:
[image]

As you can see, the actual generated rig is way to small and burred within the model. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Note: My object is at 0, 0, 0 and scaled 1, 1, 1.

Comment: What about the scale of your meta-rig?  Try applying scale (ctrl-A scale) to meta-rig before generating the rig.

Comment: @batFINGER yeah it's at 1.0. When I scale it up a ton it works. I guess I figured that the rig scale was supposed to match up with my object size, but if that's normal, then I'm good. Sorry for a dumb question like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just scale it as you would with other objects. While in object mode, select the armature and then press S to scale it.

Answer (score 4):

1. Select rig
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>
3. Apply transforms
4. Generate rig